# PhoneGap: mediaRec.startRecord(); not working in cordova-1.7.0

Tags: iphone, cordova

I'm trying to record a sample audio with phoneGap(cordova 1.7.0), but it is not working.

here is the code

```
    function startRecord() {
    var src = "testrecord.wav";
    alert("startRecord: "+src);
    navigator.mediaRec = new Media(src, onSuccessRecord, onErrorRecord);

    // Record audio
    navigator.mediaRec.startRecord();

    // Stop recording after 10 sec
    var recTime = 0;
    var recInterval = setInterval(function() {
                                  recTime = recTime + 1;
                                  //setAudioPosition(recTime + " sec");
                                  if (recTime >= 10) {
                                  clearInterval(recInterval);
                                  navigator.mediaRec.stopRecord();
                                  }

                                  }, 1000);
    }


function onSuccessRecord() {

    //alert("recordAudio():Audio Success");
    var src = "testrecord.wav";
    playRecordedAudio(src);

}

function playRecordedAudio(src) {

    // Create Media object from src
    //alert("play: "+src);
    navigator.my_media = new Media(src, onSuccessPlay, onErrorRecord);

    // Play audio
    navigator.my_media.play();

}
// onError Callback 
//

function onSuccessPlay() {
    console.log("playAudio():Audio Success");
}

function onErrorRecord(error) {
    alert('code: '    + error.code    + '\n' + 
          'message: ' + error.message + '\n');
    }
```

I have tried this in xcode simulator and its worked fine, but not in iphone
Can anyone please help me out?

Answer (score 0):

For the iphone the recording file (in your case testrecord.wav) has to exists before you start recording. Make sure that it exists by using the Phonegap [File API](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.3.0/cordova_file_file.md.html).